# Per field ranking in Sphinx

Tags: sphinx

I have a Sphinx index with three indexed fields. I would like to rank higher those documents with matches on field one over those on field two and then again those over field three, so that for example a document with one match on field one would outrank a document with multiple matches in field two. How can I go about doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the SetFieldWeights API function

http://sphinxsearch.com/docs/current.html#api-func-setfieldweights